# Stored procedure with output parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Trying to create a Stored procedure that will give the required no. of records and also the total no. of records in that table.

The '@Query' part gives result when I execute it separately. So there's no problem with that.
Could Someone please check if the syntax is correct, cause I'm not getting at any result.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetRecordsByPage    
(    
  @TableName nvarchar(50),    
  @ColumnName nvarchar(50),    
  @OrderByClause nvarchar(50),    
  @StartIndex nvarchar(50),    
  @EndIndex nvarchar(50),    
  @TotalRows nvarchar(50) output    
)    
AS    
BEGIN    
  DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max)    

  select @Query = 'select '+@TotalRows+' = count(*) from '+@TableName+' 
                   where deleted=0

                   with temp as (select row_number() over (order by '+    
                   @colname+' '+@OrderByClause+') as row, * from '+@tablename+')

                   select * from temp where row between '+@startIndex+' and '
                   +@EndIndex    

   execute sp_executesql @Query, @TotalRows output 

END
--is this correct, to test this stored procedure
-- execute GetRecordsByPage 'tblBranch','BranchName', '2', '10'
```

Otherwise, the queries would be:

```
select count(*) from tblBranch;
With temp as
(select row_number over(order by name desc) as row, * from tblbranch)
select * from temp where row between 11 and 20;
```

Comment: you are assigning int to @TotalRows which is of type nvarchar

Comment: If assigning to a `NVARCHAR` variable, you should use the `N'...'` to indicate Unicode. Next: you **must** put a semicolon (`;`) before the `with` keyword.

Comment: write query like  select @Query = 'select count(*) ....

Comment: @Terror.Blade. How Should I store it in a variable then.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetRecordsByPage    
(    
  @TableName nvarchar(50),    
  @ColumnName nvarchar(50),    
  @OrderByClause nvarchar(50),    
  @StartIndex nvarchar(50),    
  @EndIndex nvarchar(50),    
  @TotalRows nvarchar(50) output    
)    
AS    
BEGIN    
  DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max)    

  select @Query = 'select @TotalRowsOut = count(*) from '+@TableName+' 
                   where deleted=0

                   with temp as (select row_number() over (order by '+    
                   @colname+' '+@OrderByClause+') as row, * from '+@tablename+')

                   select * from temp where row between '+@startIndex+' and '
                   +@EndIndex    

    DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@TotalRowsOut int OUTPUT';
       execute sp_executesql @Query,  @ParmDefinition,@TotalRowsOut=@TotalRows output 
select @TotalRows
END
```

Comment: You have declared it as int in paramDefinition. The first declaration was nvarchar. So shold I also change that to int. Why is there an extra comma/param after @query in the exec statement. I'm assuming that the final execute statement to test the procedure is correct...is it

Comment: execute GetRecordsByPage 'tblBranch','BranchName', '2', '10', /@TotalRows output - gives an error- must declare scalar variable /@TotalRows - But isnt it already declared

Comment: y are you putting /@totalrows use  GetRecordsByPage 'tblBranch','BranchName', '2', '10', @TotalRows

Comment: When using just '@'...it isnt allowing to submit. It thinks thts a username. The line's just as you wrote, but with 'output at the end

Comment: how you call it is it c#.. i am just asking

Comment: Yes,it is c#. But I havent got that far yet. I just want to check if this SP is working first.

Comment: just go through ths link of microsoft you will get idea http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262499

Comment: I looked at method 2, but that's what you have suggested already. What else need to be done here?